# Finding common elements between two files

Tags: python

I have two different files as follows:
file1.txt is tab-delimited

```
AT5G54940.1 3182
            pfam
            PF01253 SUI1#Translation initiation factor SUI1
            mf
            GO:0003743  translation initiation factor activity
            GO:0008135  translation factor activity, nucleic acid binding
            bp
            GO:0006413  translational initiation
            GO:0006412  translation
            GO:0044260  cellular macromolecule metabolic process
GRMZM2G158629_P02   4996
                pfam
                PF01575 MaoC_dehydratas#MaoC like domain
                mf
                GO:0016491  oxidoreductase activity
                GO:0033989  3alpha,7alpha,
OS08T0174000-01 560919
```

and file2.txt that contains different protein names,

```
GRMZM2G158629_P02
AT5G54940.1
OS05T0566300-01
OS08T0174000-01
```

I need to run a program, that finds me proteins names that are present in file2 from file1 but also prints me all "GO:" that appertains to that protein, if applicable. The difficult part for me is parsing the 1st file..the format is strange. I tried something like this,but any other ways are very much appreciated,

```
import re
with open('file2.txt') as mylist:                                                      
proteins = set(line.strip() for line in mylist)                         

with open('file1.txt') as mydict:                           
    with open('a.txt', 'w') as output:                  
        for line in mydict:                                 
            new_list = line.strip().split()                         
            protein = new_list[0]                               
            if protein in proteins:
                if re.search(r'GO:\d+', line):
                    output.write(protein+'\t'+line)
```

Desired output,whichever format is OK as long as I have all corresponding GO's

```
AT5G54940.1 GO:0003743  translation initiation factor activity
            GO:0008135  translation factor activity, nucleic acid binding
            GO:0006413  translational initiation
            GO:0006412  translation
            GO:0044260  cellular macromolecule metabolic process
GRMZM2G158629_P02   GO:0016491  oxidoreductase activity
                    GO:0033989  3alpha,7alpha,
OS08T0174000-01
```

Comment: can u add one or two more protein detail at file1. just as test case.

Comment: sure thing! it is tab-delimited btw...

Comment: Does the whole "word" on a single line in file2.txt count as a protein name??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give you an idea how you might want to tackle this. A "group" belonging to one protein in your input file is delimited by a change from indented lines to a non-indented one. Search for this transition and you have your groups (or "chunks"). The first line of a group contains the protein name. All other lines might be GO: lines.

You can detect indention by using `if line.startswith(" ")` (instead of `" "` you might look for `"\t"`, depending on your input file format).

```
def get_protein_chunks(filepath):
    chunk = []
    last_indented = False
    with open(filepath) as f:
        for line in f:
            if not line.startswith(" "):
                current_indented = False
            else:
                current_indented = True
            if last_indented and not current_indented:
                yield chunk
                chunk = []       
            chunk.append(line.strip())
            last_indented = current_indented


look_for_proteins = set(line.strip() for line in open('file2.txt'))


for p in get_protein_chunks("input.txt"):
    proteinname = p[0].split()[0]
    proteindata = p[1:]
    if proteinname not in look_for_proteins:
        continue
    print "Protein: %s" % proteinname
    golines = [l for l in proteindata if l.startswith("GO:")]
    for g in golines:
        print g
```

Here, a chunk is nothing but a list of stripped lines. I extract the protein chunks from the input file with a generator. As you can see, the logic is based only on the transition from indented line to non-indented line.

When using the generator you can do with the data whatever you want to. I simply printed it. However, you might want to put the data into a dictionary and do further analysis.

Output:

```
$ python test.py 
Protein: AT5G54940.1
GO:0003743  translation initiation factor activity
GO:0008135  translation factor activity, nucleic acid binding
GO:0006413  translational initiation
GO:0006412  translation
GO:0044260  cellular macromolecule metabolic process
Protein: GRMZM2G158629_P02
GO:0016491  oxidoreductase activity
GO:0033989  3alpha,7alpha,
```

Comment: thank you, sorry for a stupid question, filepath? what is that?

Comment: That is the formal name of a function argument. When the function (in this case a "generator") is called, a value is set: `get_protein_chunks("input.txt")`, in this case the variable `filepath` carries the value `"input.txt"`.

Comment: Ah OK I havent seen this line 
look_for_proteins = set(line.strip() for line in open('file2.txt')), now it is clear, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to build up a dictionary of lists, using the name of the protein as the key:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()

proteins = set(line.strip() for line in open('file2.txt'))
d = {}

with open('file1.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        parts = line.split()

        if parts[0] in proteins:
            key = parts[0]            
            d[key] = []                            
        elif parts[0].split(':')[0] == 'GO':
            d[key].append(line)

pp.pprint(d)
```

I've used the `pprint` module to print the dictionary, as you said you weren't too fussy about the format. The output as it stands is:

```
{'AT5G54940.1': ['GO:0003743  translation initiation factor activity',
                 'GO:0008135  translation factor activity, nucleic acid binding',
                 'GO:0006413  translational initiation',
                 'GO:0006412  translation',
                 'GO:0044260  cellular macromolecule metabolic process'],
 'GRMZM2G158629_P02': ['GO:0016491  oxidoreductase activity',
                       'GO:0033989  3alpha,7alpha,']}
```

---

#### edit

Instead of using `pprint`, you could obtain the output specified in the question using a loop:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as out:    
    for k,v in d.iteritems():        
        out.write('Protein: {}\n'.format(k))
        out.write('{}\n'.format('\n'.join(v)))
```

`out.txt`:

```
Protein: GRMZM2G158629_P02
GO:0016491  oxidoreductase activity
GO:0033989  3alpha,7alpha,
Protein: AT5G54940.1
GO:0003743  translation initiation factor activity
GO:0008135  translation factor activity, nucleic acid binding
GO:0006413  translational initiation
GO:0006412  translation
GO:0044260  cellular macromolecule metabolic process
```

Comment: I see, you do not at all split the protein data file into groups, you just consider any line as potential protein name carrier. Might be correct, might be not. Just with my approach, I am not sure if the indention-based group identification is reliable or not.

Comment: @user3224522 I haven't done that before but I've edited my answer to show how you could get the output specified in the question.